How to sort a queryset by a attributes's choices
I have a model on Django (5.0.4) with a selectable month and year, like so:
class Item(models.Model):
    MONTHS_CHOICES = [
        ('JANUARY', 'January'),
        ('FEBRUARY', 'February'),
        ('MARCH', 'March'),
        ('APRIL', 'April'),
        ('MAY', 'May'),
        ('JUNE', 'June'),
        ('JULY', 'July'),
        ('AUGUST', 'August'),
        ('SEPTEMBER', 'September'),
        ('OCTOBER', 'October'),
        ('NOVEMBER', 'November'),
        ('DECEMBER', 'December')
    ]
    month = models.CharField(max_length=9, choices=MONTHS_CHOICES, default="JANUARY",  db_index=True)
    year = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    (...)


If I try to order the items by month  and year Item.objects.all().order_by("-year", "month").
Logically the months will be be ordered alphabetically.
What can I do to get the items ordered by the same order I have the months on MONTHS_CHOICES?
Option B is just redo the models to include a DateField with only year and month, like this question here and order it by that field
I also tried the solutions on this page but nothing worked to me.

I haven't had a chance to test this out yet myself, but my guess would be using the name of the month as a 'Key' in a dictionary, where the corresponding 'Value' is the appropriate month's ordinal value (i.e. Jan -> 1, Feb -> 2, etc.)
Here's my thoughts for how this might look:
class Item(models.Model):
    MONTHS_CHOICES = [
        ('JANUARY', 'January'),
        ('FEBRUARY', 'February'),
        ('MARCH', 'March'),
        ('APRIL', 'April'),
        ('MAY', 'May'),
        ('JUNE', 'June'),
        ('JULY', 'July'),
        ('AUGUST', 'August'),
        ('SEPTEMBER', 'September'),
        ('OCTOBER', 'October'),
        ('NOVEMBER', 'November'),
        ('DECEMBER', 'December')
    ]
    MONTHS_ORDER = {
        'JANUARY': 1,
        'FEBRUARY': 2,
        'MARCH': 3, 
        'APRIL': 4, 
        'MAY': 5,
        'JUNE': 6,
        'JULY': 7, 
        'AUGUST': 8, 
        'SEPTEMBER': 9, 
        'OCTOBER': 10,
        'NOVEMBER': 11,
        'DECEMBER': 12
    }
    month = models.CharField(max_length=9, choices=MONTHS_CHOICES, default="JANUARY",  db_index=True)
    month_numeric = models.IntegerField(editable=False, db_index=True)
    year = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def (self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.month_numeric = self.MONTHS_ORDER[self.month]
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

NOTE: If you already have data in your DB, you will need to edit your migration file to set this automatically for objects already stored in your DB. Again, untested but something like the below I imagine:
def populate_month_numeric(apps, schema_editor):
    Item = apps.get_model('YOUR APP NAME - CHANGE THIS!', 'Item')
    for item in Item.objects.all():
        item.month_numeric = Item.MONTHS_ORDER[item.month]
        item.save() 

Then once you've run makemigrations, open the migration file created and in your Migration class's operations field, add the following near the end:
migrations.RunPython(populate_month_numeric)
Then of course actually run the migrate function, and your queries should be doable like the below:
items = Item.objects.all().order_by("-year", "month_numeric")

As I say, haven't run this code myself yet, but this aspect of 'Key' -> 'Value' mapping is how I've solved similar issues in the past!

Thanks! Works like a charm. Don't worry about migrations and data, this is just a mock-up project so I could easily delete them to make things easier.
My only concern about this approach: is it OK to overwrite the save() method?

Very pleased to hear that @Germán, thanks for commenting and accepting. Yes, absolutely fine to overwrite the save() method in situations like this - in fact, it is considered best practice. Just make sure to always call 'super()' appropriately so that your changes actually register to the database.

If you have a free choice with the DB field, then don't use a CharField with a month name. Use an IntegerField with choices:
MONTHS_CHOICES = [
    ( 1, 'January'),
    ( 2, 'February'),
    ( 3, 'March'),
    ...
]

The numbers are arbitrary, If for some reason (UK tax years!) you wanted April to be 1 and March to be 12, then code that.
For templates displaying this field or Python code where you want the month name, use
{{ item_instance.get_month_display }}

or in Python
month_name = item_instance.get_month_display()

